# How to just change object property values that exists?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a backend API and storing all data in a array for now because I'm still learning.

I need to update the object properties on the array based on a put request. I just want to replace the data requested by the client and the rest must remains the same.

I just know how to do it hard coding each property like Arr.propertyA = req.body.propetyA...

I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

Here is the code for clarity:

backend

```
const books = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Book 1',
        author: 'Author 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Book 2',
        author: 'Author 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Book 3',
        author: 'Author 3'
    }
]

app.put('/api/books/:id', (req, res) => {
    const foundIndex = books.findIndex(book => { return req.params.id == book.id });
    books[foundIndex] = req.body;

    res.send(books[foundIndex]);
}
```

front-end

```
PUT: 

url: http://localhost:5000/api/books/1

{
    "title": "New Book 1",
    "author": "New Author 1"
}
```

result:

```
{
    title: 'New Book 1',
    author: 'New Author 1'
}
```

but I expect

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'New Book 1',
    author: 'New Author 1'
}
```

============ EDIT ==================

Full function for better understanding

```
app.put("/api/books/:id", (req, res) => {
  const schema = {
    title: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .required(),
    author: Joi.string()
  };

  // Look up the course
  const book = books.find(book => {
    return req.params.id == book.id;
  });

  // If not existing, return 404
  if (book.length === 0) {
    res.status(404).send(`The book with ID: "${req.params.id}" was not found`);
    return;
  }

  // Validate
  const validation = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);

  // If invalid, return 400 - Bad request
  if (validation.error) {
    res.status(400).send(validation.error.details[0].message);
    return;
  }

  // Update the course
  Object.assign(book, req.body);

  // Return the updated course
  res.send(book);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the matching `id` is found, use `Object.assign` to merge the `req.body` object onto the book. (Since you don't really care about the found index, only about the book object at that index, better to use `.find` than `.findIndex`):

```
app.put('/api/books/:id', (req, res) => {
    const book = books.find(book => { return req.params.id == book.id });
    Object.assign(book, req.body);
    res.send(book);
});
```

If there's any chance that there will not be a matching book for the `req.params.id`, make sure to check that `book` exists first before trying to do stuff with it.

*If*, like in your example, a book's `id` always matches its position in the `books` array, it would be easier to use bracket notation to just access the right index, instead of using `.find`:

```
app.put('/api/books/:id', (req, res) => {
    const book = books[req.params.id];
    Object.assign(book, req.body);
    res.send(book);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. Very helpfull. I kinda thought about object.Assign() but was not sure. Thanks for the advice about the find/findIndex feature. I'm already making sure the object exists and matches the schema but I didn't post it here. Now as I'm already filtering it, perhaps I can do what you mention to assign it directly without find.

Comment: I refactored my code. It was smelling. I reviewed and saw I was already filtering the object at the beginning of the function. So I just took out all that overhead and replaced by Object.assign(book, req.body); But interestingly the object was not updating. It was because I was using filter so I changed for find method and worked like a charm. Seems like filter don't allow to mutate the object.

Comment: I'll edit to post the full function so you'll have a overall idea of it just to clarify. Anyways, thanks for your inshgts. I'm still learning but feels really great to refactor code, make it better.

Comment: `.filter` should be fine, it won't create a copy of the array items, it'll only create a copy of the array: https://jsfiddle.net/g9h3rjkz/ so if one of the items is mutated, the item in the original array will be mutated as well.

Comment: Note that in the code in your question, `book` will be either a book object or `undefined`. It doesn't have a `length` property. If you want to check if the book doesn't exist, check `if (!book) { /* errors */ }`

Comment: I see. I tried to use if (!book) before but was not working. I Realized now based on your fiddle that I didn't specify to return just the first object match of the books array [0]. So it was returning [{title: '', author: ''}] instead of {title: '', author: ''}

Comment: Now it's perfect dudeee =D

Comment: I believe the best is find though because it returns the first match and stops. Filter return all matches, so it will go through all array.

Comment: Yes, if you only need the first match, because it'll be the only match, `.find` is the right choice.